# What will happen to the custom font in application once the user changes the phone's font?

Tags: android, fonts, custom-font

I'm planning to implement custom font into an application and I knew that android user can change to other font as they want. So my question is that what will happen to the custom font in the application once the user changes the phone's font? Will it changes all the font include the custom font as well? I don't have an android phone to test it out, can someone answer my doubt? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a custom font, your app will not be using the phones default font and thus it is not attached to the font set by the phone. It should not be effected

Comment: So you mean that if I set it to custom font, the font wont be effected even the user change the phone font?

Comment: That is exactly what im saying

Answer (score 2):

If you use custom fonts in your app, it will prioritize the custom font instead of the default font of the phone.